# Create a generic Class to accept 2 database Connections

Tags: java, jdbc, h2, spring-jdbc

I want to create a class which can accept 2 database connections as required by the user mainly H2 database and MSSQL.

Can someone provide a pseudocode or a sample code. How to go about it?

I need to just pass the parameters for connectivity.

```
public class H2databaseconnection
{
private static final String DB_FILE_NAME=...

Connection properties for H2..
//Pretty simple code for h2
}

Public class connectionMSSQL{

{
Connection code for MSSQL
//Pretty simple code for MSSQL
}
```

I have been able to make connections with a database using both connections.

As I am working on an API, I don't understand how will I make a particular call to such classes with what parameters, depending on the person having H2 database or MSSQL database.

If he has H2/MSSQL, what parameters should he pass?

Created a class with main function:

```
public connectivity {
    public static void main(String args[] _) {
        Connection con = new H2databaseconnection().getConnection();
        String query = "Select * from abc where ghj = 'a65e'";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println(colCount);

        // stmt.close();
        // con.close();

        Connection con1 = new ConnectionMSSQL().getConnection();
        String query1 = "Select * from xyz where abc = '05e'";
        Statement stmt1 = con1.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(query1);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd1 = rs1.getMetaData();
        int colCount1 = rsmd1.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println(colCount1);

    }
}
```

I am able to connect. But how to go about user giving parameters for connectivity?

Comment: you can write factory to get connections.

Comment: Code-requests are off-topic for StackOverflow. Show what you've tried and detail the specific problem(s) and make sure you have an objective, answerable question.

Comment: @AbhishekGarg Thank you! I will vote to re-open the question if it's no longer too broad after your update :)

Comment: @tnw I hope the question is more open now..?

Comment: @AbhishekGarg Still too broad as your code doesn't demonstrate an actual issue as it isn't code. And you're still requesting code.

Comment: @tnw .. Oh Man!! :P Let me give it a last try.

Comment: @tnw If its ok now.? Otherwise you can remove the question.

Comment: @abhi5800 Thanks for the update, but you're still just asking for code. Try what you're asking for yourself. A better question would be to ask about specific issues you're encountering with the code. I'm not a moderator so I can't remove your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
import java.sql.Connection;

public class PairedDatabaseConnection {

    public PairedDatabaseConnection(
        final Connection primaryConnection, final Connection secondaryConnection) {
        // validation connections are not null
        this.primaryConnection = primaryConnection;
        this.secondaryConnection = secondaryConnection;
    }

    private final Connection primaryConnection;
    private final Connection secondaryConnection;
}
```

Comment: This is actually similar approach to factory method. 1)Hold references object instances or way to instantiate object(lazy load). 2)Ask factory for any of them.